# Why is my "vmlinuz file" missing during a USB dual boot Ubuntu installation?

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, bootloader, usb-installation, rufus

I have done OS installations in the past, but for some reason this time I'm having trouble. I am running a desktop with Windows 10 already installed and wanting to install Ubuntu alongside. I partitioned my second 2tb drive to install Ubuntu on the 800gb that I've provided. I downloaded the Ubuntu latest iso file, and used Rufus to burn it onto my 16gb USB stick. Then I booted my machine to the USB stick, and then the Ubuntu logo popped up. Heres  where things get wierd... I waited for a while and Ubuntu just kept on loading. So I thought it froze. But then I pressed the arrow key and saw the terminal with a ton of errors and Ubuntu trying to restart those services over and over.

[Services crashing and restarting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIwQd.jpg)
I then went back and used different settings in Rufus(such as changing the partition scheme to gpt, and using the "dd" method). Then I got different results. The error '/casper/vmlinuz: file not found' was now the issue.

[Error "vmlinuz file was not found"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iikVx.jpg)
It it the problem with Rufus, or my settings? I downloaded the latest Desktop
Ubuntu 18.04.4 iso.

Comment: Did you verify your downloaded ISO was perfect? and the the write to your install media was equally flawless?  You've skipped normal error checking procedures and then been a little vague on some (Ubuntu 18.04.4 Server? Desktop? etc).  https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck (where CD refers to any install media used, be it CD/DVD/hdd/ssd/thumb-drive/flash-drive/... and as you didn't specify desktop/server/cloud/.. these may not be most appropriate links for you)

Comment: I'm installing the Desktop version of Ubuntu. I should've mentioned that.

Comment: And yes, I did verify the ISO through Windows Ubuntu terminal, and the ISO is clean and verified.

Comment: The write to media is where I have the most problems, and you still haven't mentioned that (ie. validation of install media, or write of ISO to install media).  It takes seconds, but if it was flawed you'll waste days-weeks finding and fixing the flaws introduced by bad bits written to install media.  I think of it as really cheap insurance..

Comment: I used Rufus to write it to my usb stick. I had the default settings set. Do you have a recommendation of a different way of burning it to usb? By the way, I've also tried Etcher - which gave me an error of hashes not matching, and LinuxLive - which also didnt work. I already mentioned that I have verified the ISO that I've downloaded, so I dont understand why Etcher is outputting that error...